# PHP Prepared Statements: Echo the Result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i want to Display the Result ('Positio: 2' or 'Position: 1') via a Echo
but $statement is  a Object of class PDOStatement and not a String, how do i get it to see only the result of $statement? Thank you

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb1', 'root', '');

    $idV = $_GET['id'];

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT position FROM idtabelle WHERE idnumber = ?");
$statement->execute(array($idV));

echo "Position: //$result_Of_Statement\\  ";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT position FROM idtabelle WHERE idnumber = :idV");
$statement->bindParam(':idV', $idV);
$statement->execute();
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  echo $row['position'];
}
```

You could also do away with the while loop if you wanted to.

Comment: it works, but only with while Why? I just need one thing back, so i still need the while?

Comment: You don't need the while with only one result. You can remove the while. Also, please +1 and accept this as the answer if it helped you. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would fetch the result and use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see the result quickly.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT position FROM idtabelle WHERE idnumber = ?");
$statement->execute(array($idV));
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Or fetchAll()
echo "Position: ". print_r($result);
```

That's a quick and dirty way to inspect the result. If you want to add some formatting:

```
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
for( $result as $key=>$value ){
    echo ucfirst($key) .": $value \n";
}
```

If you want to get multiple rows wrap that in a loop where you fetch a new row each iteration

```
while( $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
  echo "===New Row===";
  for( $result as $key=>$value ){
    echo ucfirst($key) .": $value \n";
  }
}
```